# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Two keys to compare)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, insert, duplicates

What I want to do is to just increment the 4th column of the value that it should've been if it didn't existed, when a row that has `col0 = valuecol0 AND col2 = valuecol2` is in the table.
Otherwise, I want to insert the row, of course.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col0, col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (valuecol0, valuecol1, valuecol2, valuecol3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = col3 + VALUES( col3 );
```

Anyway, I can't figure out how I should set the INDEXes in the table, I read the page in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) but it wans't much of help. So I tried all the four possible combination and no one worked!

Where am I failing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To generate a key violation, you can use a unique index:

```
create unique index IX_YourTable_Col0Col2 on YourTable (col0, col2);
```

With this index, you can use the `on duplicate key update` syntax:

```
insert into YourTable (col0, col1, col2, col3) 
values (1, 2, 1, 2) 
on duplicate key update col3 = col3 + 2;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb9ed7/1/0)

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me this line: create unique index IX_YourTable_Col0Col2 on YourTable (col0, col2); Specifically: What convention does the name IX_YourTable_Col0Col2 respect? How would you read the whole line?

Comment: `IX_YourTable_Col0Col2` is just a name.  Prefix should've been `UX_` for unique index :)  The third variant is `PK_` for primary key.   For the entire line, see the documentation for [`create index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)